# Same regex but different result on different computer

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

Me and one of my coworker use the same regex but we obtain different result and we are currently clueless... The regex is supose to find anything that start with (byte) follow by anything that's not a ( or ) and is follow by a + sign. I obtain the good result but not him. 
We both use IntelliJ 14.1.14 and use the regex in the IntelliJ search engine. 
Anyone has experience it and solve it?

Regex :

```
\(byte\)[^()]*\+
```

Data :

```
(byte)'a' + 1;
(byte)'-';
```

My result :

```
(byte)'a' +
```

His result :

```
(byte)'-';
```

Comment: what are you using and what is he using for a regex lib

Comment: We both use the IntelliJ search engine

Comment: Are you both doing your own code, or is this like a file in source control you both are using?  Are you sure everything is identical?

Comment: All things being equal, `\(byte\)[^()]*\+` will not match `(byte)'a' + 1;`, but it will match `(byte)'a' +`. So, this is suspicious indeed.

Comment: @dustmouse It's the same file from a source control, the only thing that may differ is our IntelliJ setting, but we didn't found anything that look like it could alter our regex.

Comment: @sln yes indeed I should have write `(byte)'a' +` in my result, Im changing it right away

Comment: @ajanelle there **must** be something different on "his" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ supports several SDKs. For example, in paid version, in addition to Java you could use a plug-in for Python (duplicating their PyCharm product). The [regular expression engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) will vary based on the [SDK being used](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html).

However, as indicated by sln, your expression: `\(byte\)[^()]*\+` will never match the text `(byte)'-';` (regardless of the engine being used) because your regex mandates that a matching line end with a `+` symbol, which is not the case with his result.

Therefore, I think he has an error in his expression; it's not a problem with IntelliJ, or even a difference in engines. You might want to use the [regex101](https://regex101.com/) site to experiment further.

It's possible that he doesn't have a bug on his side and that a difference in file encodings is causing this (though I don't know what particular mismatch would.) Try ensuring that you're both [using the same encoding](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-encodings.html), UTF-8 being a good default.

Comment: @ajanelle Did this help?

Comment: It wasn't it, we still didn't figure what the problem was we try on another computer and it work... It's only one computer for a unknown reason that as the problem.. Thank for the help and sorry for the time I took to respond I was away. I put your answer as the solution so it may help someone because it could have been it